# Winapp driver : How to select items from the list using Java

Tags: winappdriver

I am trying to automate Windows app using Win app driver, How can we select item from the list using java?

```
WindowsElement comboBoxElement1=  (WindowsElement) DesktopSession.findElementsByXPath("//List[@Name='Select Outlet:']//*[starts-with(@AutomationId,'listBox')]");
comboBoxElement1.findElementByName("!xyz").click();
```

I am getting error as not being able to locate the element. Also  most of the cases `findElementByXpath` is not working.

UI looks as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sendkeys:

```
comboBoxElement1.SendKeys("name of the item");
```

UPDATE

```
comboBox.Click(); 
string xPathListItem = $"//Text[contains(@Name, '{dateTom}')]/preceding::Custom[1]/ComboBox/ListItem[1]"; //xPath of your item in combobox
 elem = (WindowsElement)window.FindElementByXPath(xPathListItem);
app.DoubleClick(elem);
```

here is my DoubleClick method:

```
public void DoubleClick(WindowsElement elem)
        {
            session.Mouse.MouseMove(elem.Coordinates);
            session.Mouse.DoubleClick(null);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Kishore. I tried with SendKeys, its not able to find the element.

Comment: To be honest, it works sometime. and sometime it doesn't. Even I had implemented different strategy. I will update my answer with what I had implemented.

Comment: Hi @AshwiniMC if my answer helps you, will you please mark it as answered. In this way, other member will directly go for the accepted answers.